# Вывести столбцы в определенном порядке при сохранении DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

У меня имеется список словарей, который потом конвертируется в DataFrame и сохраняется в .xlsx или .csv.
В этом случае порядок столбцов определяется по алфавиту.

Можно ли как нибудь закрепить определенный порядок этих столбцов?

```
def save_result(items):
    print("Сохранение результатов")
    df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    df.to_excel("result.xlsx", index=False)
    df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 1):

Задавайте порядок при экспорте в файл:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.to_csv(filename, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

[Документация](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный способ получить столбцы фрейма в нужном порядке:

```
cols = [“col_a”, ..., “col_n”]
df = df[cols]
```